# Why is there a relationship between symmetries and conservation laws?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

I am reading through my professor's notes and I am unsure as to what the intimate relationship between the symmetry property of a physical system and the conservation laws of energy, momentum, and angular moment are related to each other.

Like, I can see the latter two being related to conservation of energy, but how do they relate to symmetry property for a physical system?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy conservation is a consequence of a system’s invariance under time translations. Momentum conservation is a consequence of a system’s invariance under spatial translations. Angular momentum conservation is a consequence of of system’s invariance under rotations.

These relationships are all examples of [Noether’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), named after the celebrated female mathematician [Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether), “the most important woman in the history of mathematics”.